# PHP form having problems when adding new fields

Tags: php, forms

I have purchased the following script from codecanyon

http://codecanyon.net/item/contact-me-contact-form-admin-panel-v2/148836

and then I have added the script into my website template.
I added a new field under the $fname variable.

BEFORE edit:

```
<label>First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" style="width:400px;" value="<?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>" />
```

AFTER edit:

```
<select type="select" name="fname" id="colorselector" class="styled" value="<?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>" />
   <option value="slct">Please select a forum you saw me on</option>
   <option value="hf <?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>">Hackforums (_Jony_)</option>
   <option value="sy <?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>">Sythe (Purepks0r)</option>
   <option value="rs <?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>">R-S (Purepks0r)</option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="slct" class="colors">You haven't selected any forum.</div>
<div id="hf" class="colors" style="display:none"> <span id="brdr">HackForums:</span> Discount Percent: <font color="green">10%</font> </div>
<div id="sy" class="colors" style="display:none"> <span id="brdr">Sythe:</span> Discount Percent: <font color="green">15%</font> </div>
<div id="rs" class="colors" style="display:none"> <span id="brdr">Rune-Server:</span> Discount Percent: <font color="green">15%</font> </div>
<br />
```

Basically i used fname for a select tag, it should do the same, store the selected information to admin panel.

I tried restoring the code to default and it worked, why does it say the field is blank when i actually selected the drop down?

the error checking system:

Im not sure but ill give out the order.php page and config.ini

Order.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('captcha/Captcha.php');
$captcha = new Captcha();
$captcha->newCaptcha(session_id());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<title>SlyFiles</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="SlyFiles upload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css"><script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script><!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links --><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">$(window).load(function() {  $('.flexslider').flexslider({    animation: "slide"  });});</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
<a href="index.php"><div id="logo"></div></a>
<a href="index.php"><div id="home"></div></a>
<a href="portfolio.php"><div id="portfolio"></div></a>
<a href="vouch.php"><div id="vouch"></div></a>
<a href="tos.php"><div id="tos"></div></a>
<a href="order.php"><div id="order-current"></div></a>
  </div>
  <div id="banner"></div>
  <div id="borderbottom"></div>
</div>
</header>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="forms">
    <form action="next.php?c=Zm5leHQ=" method="post">
    <br /><br /><center><?php
    /*
        This code should be where you want your error messages shown.
    */
    //Edit this according to your design taste
    $errStyle = 'border: 1px solid red; color: red; width: 410px; padding: 5px; margin: 0 0 15px 0;';
    //----------------------------------
    //----No editing from here----
    //----------------------------------
    /*
        This script displays errors from the form, if any. To edit the messages itself, see err_message.php in the same folder.
    */
    include_once 'err_message.php';
    $no = base64_decode(htmlentities(strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'no'))));
    if($no == NULL) {} else {
    print <<<HERE
    <div style="max-width: 600px; float: left;" class="alert alert-error">
HERE;
    print $errorMes[$no];
    if($errorMes[$no]==NULL) print '<script>location.href="javascript: history.go(-1)"</script>';
    print '</div>';
    }
    ?></center>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="tos1">
<input type="checkbox" id="new_info_yes" class="box1"> I agree to the <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>.
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="creater">
<div id="new_info_form">
<select type="select" name="fname" id="colorselector" class="styled" value="<?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>" />
   <option value="slct">Please select a forum you saw me on</option>
   <option value="hf <?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>">Hackforums (_Jony_)</option>
   <option value="sy <?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>">Sythe (Purepks0r)</option>
   <option value="rs <?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>">R-S (Purepks0r)</option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="slct" class="colors">You haven't selected any forum.</div>
<div id="hf" class="colors" style="display:none"> <span id="brdr">HackForums:</span> Discount Percent: <font color="green">10%</font> </div>
<div id="sy" class="colors" style="display:none"> <span id="brdr">Sythe:</span> Discount Percent: <font color="green">15%</font> </div>
<div id="rs" class="colors" style="display:none"> <span id="brdr">Rune-Server:</span> Discount Percent: <font color="green">15%</font> </div>
<br />

    <label>Last Name:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="lastName" style="width:420px;" value="<?php if($_GET['sname']) echo urldecode($_GET['sname']); ?>" />

    <label>Phone Number:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="phone" style="width:420px;" value="<?php if($_GET['phoneno']) echo urldecode($_GET['phoneno']); ?>" />

    <label>Email Address:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="email1" style="width:420px;" value="<?php if($_GET['email']) echo urldecode($_GET['email']); ?>" />

    <label>Confirm Email Address:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="email2" style="width:420px;" />

    <label>Message:</label> 
    <textarea name="message" style="width:420px;height:150px;" ><?php if($_GET['mes']) echo urldecode($_GET['mes']); ?></textarea>
<br />
        <img src="captcha/image.php?sid=<?php echo session_id(); ?>&color=grey" alt="" />
        <label>Captcha:</label>
        <input type="text" name="captcha" style="width:400px;" />
<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" style="background: #575757; color: #ffffff; border: none; padding: 3px 5px; width:420px; height:40px;" />

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input#upload_yes').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#upload_form").show();
        } else {
            $("#upload_form").hide();
        }
    });

    $('input#new_info_yes').change(function(){
         if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#new_info_form").slideDown(500);
        } else {
                $("#new_info_form").delay(300).slideUp(500);;
        }   
    });

    //Trigger the change event so the divs are initially shown or hidden.
    $('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('change');

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#colorselector').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
    </script> 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
<div class="container">
  <div class="footer">
  <span id="footer">
  JonyDesigners &copy; 2012, All rights reserved.
  </div>
</div>
</footer>
<script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/rapturesgfx.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Config.ini

```
<?php

/*
This file sets up all the MySQL database and tables, as well as the functions needed in other scripts.
You should only edit the next few lines.
*/

//Change these two variables to your own MySQL username and password.
$mysqluser = "justxpp1_test";
$mysqlpass = "censored";

//Change this variable to your MySQL host's name.
$mysqlhost = "localhost";

//Change this variable to the file path of the form.
$form = "order.php";

//This variable defines the database name.
$dbname = "justxpp1_test";

//Captcha toggle
$captchatoggle = TRUE;

//--------------------------------------------------
//----------Do not alter beyond this point----------
//--------------------------------------------------

//Starts session
session_start();

require_once('captcha/Captcha.php');
$captchaobject = new Captcha();

//Establish MySQL connection
$dbp = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpass);
if(!$dbp) die('There was an error while connecting to the database'.mysql_error());
//This part sets up the database if not set up already
$result = mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$dbname`;", $dbp);mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbp);
//Creates table named "records"
$result = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,firstname VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,surname VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,email VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,phoneno VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL, message TEXT NOT NULL, date VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, replied TEXT NOT NULL, reply TEXT NOT NULL);", $dbp);
//Creates table named "administrators"
$result = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS administrators (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,username VARCHAR (12) NOT NULL,password VARCHAR (137) NOT NULL,adminemailaddress VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,notificationoption TEXT NOT NULL);", $dbp);
//Creates an administrative account with username 'admin' and password 'admin'
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO administrators VALUES(1, 'admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', 'example@example.com', 'no');", $dbp);
//Stop error from being output to the page
error_reporting(0);
//Declare functions needed for the rest of script
function gotoPage($location) {
    print <<<HERE
    <script>location.href="$location"</script>
HERE;
}
function showErr($err_num,$fname, $username, $sname, $email, $phoneno, $mes) {
    global $form;
    $err_num = base64_encode($err_num);
        $username = urlencode($username);
        $fname = urlencode($fname);
        $sname = urlencode($sname);
        $email = urlencode($email);
        $phoneno = urlencode($phoneno);
        $mes = urlencode($mes);
    print <<<HERE
    <script>location.href="$form?no=$err_num&fname=$fname&username=$username&sname=$sname&email=$email&phoneno=$phoneno&mes=$mes"</script>
HERE;
}
function admin_showErr($place, $err_num) {
    $err_num = base64_encode($err_num);
    print <<<HERE
    <script>location.href="contactFormAdmin/$place?no=$err_num"</script>
HERE;
}
function validate($fname, $username, $sname, $email, $email_con, $phoneno, $mes, $captchaentered) {
    global $dbp;
        global $captchaobject;
        global $captchatoggle;
    if (strlen($fname)<1 || strlen($sname)<1 || strlen($email)<1 || strlen($email_con)<1 || strlen($mes)<1) {
        //Execute if one or more of the fields were less than 2 characters
        showErr(0,$fname, $sname, $username, $email, $phoneno, $mes);
    } else if($email!==$email_con) {
        //Execute if confirm email did not match email
        showErr(1,$fname, $sname, $email, $phoneno, $mes);
    } else if(strstr($email, "@")==NULL||strstr($email, ".")==NULL) {
        //Execute if email does not have an @ or a period(.)
        showErr(2,$fname, $sname, $email, $phoneno, $mes);
        } else if($captchatoggle == TRUE && ($captchaentered !== $captchaobject->getCaptcha(session_id()) || $captchaentered == null || $captchaentered == "")) {
                //Execute on captcha error
                showErr(3,$fname, $sname, $email, $phoneno, $mes);
    } else {
        //Execute if all the fields validate
        $date = date("d/M/Y");
        $new = "new";
                $noreply = "";
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO records VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$sname', '$username', '$email', '$phoneno', '$mes', '$date', '$new', '$noreply')", $dbp);
        $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM administrators WHERE id=1"));
        $adminemail = $tmp['adminemailaddress']; 
                $notificationoption = $tmp['notificationoption'];
                $esubject = "New message at Contact Me Admin!";
                $emessage = "You have received a new message in your Contact Me Admin!";
        if ($notificationoption == "yes") {mail("$adminemail","$esubject","$emessage");}
        gotoPage("success_pageForwarder.php");
    }
}
function checklogin($username, $password) {
    global $dbp;
    //Check if username and password are valid
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT password FROM administrators WHERE username='$username'", $dbp));
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT password FROM administrators WHERE username='$username'", $dbp));
    if($num_rows==0) return false;
    else if($password!==$tmp['password'])  return false;
    else if($num_rows==1&&$password==$tmp['password']) return true;
    else return false;
}
function login($username) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "$username";
    gotoPage("contactFormAdmin/panelHome.php");
}
function logout() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);
        gotoPage("contactFormAdmin/index.php");
    } else {
        gotoPage("javascript: history.go(-1)");
    }
}
function auth() {
    if((!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))||(!$_SESSION['loggedin'])) gotoPage("index.php");
}
function changepw($username, $password) {
    global $dbp;
    $password = md5($password);
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE administrators SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username';", $dbp);
    gotoPage("contactFormAdmin/panelHome.php");
}
function checkchangepw($username, $oldpw, $newpw, $newpw_con) {
    global $dbp;
    $oldpw = md5($oldpw);
    $temp = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT password FROM administrators WHERE username='$username'", $dbp));
    $realoldpw = $temp['password'];
    if($newpw!==$newpw_con) {
        admin_showErr('changePw.php', 1);
    } else if($realoldpw!==$oldpw) {
        admin_showErr('changePw.php', 3);
    } else {
        changepw($username, $newpw);
    }
}
function lastid($table) {
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM $table"));
    return $tmp['MAX(id)'];
}
function firstid($table) {
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT MIN(id) FROM $table"));
    if($tmp['MIN(id)']==NULL) return 0;
    else return $tmp['MIN(id)'];
}
function deleteRecord($id) {
    global $dbp;
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM records WHERE id=$id", $dbp);
}
?>
```

I need you guys to help me find out what is causing the system think that the select tag is being empty.

I think it has something to do with the error checking system in config.ini.

I didn't describe the problem:
When filling everything including the select option, it shows up a error message saying something is empty, after removing the code, it worked.

What is causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You have posted _way too much_ code.  Please edit your code down to only the area you suspect is causing a problem.

Comment: You should be asking these guys http://support.envato.com/

Comment: And by the way, a `<select>` tag doesn't need a `value` attribute since the value is supplied by its selected `<option>`

Comment: If it wont have a value, then how will the PHP code send it's info the the panel? :S

Comment: From the looks of things, that script depends on register_globals being on, and is incredibly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I suggest you demand your money back from this site, as they've opened your server to a total remote compromise. This code is garbage.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select type="select" name="fname" id="colorselector" class="styled" value="<?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>" />
```

Select box is closing with `</select>` not with `/>`

```
<select type="select" name="fname" id="colorselector" class="styled" value="<?php if($_GET['fname']) echo urldecode($_GET['fname']); ?>">
```

Try with that ..

```
  <select name="fname" id="colorselector" class="styled">
   <option value="slct" <?php if($_GET['fname'] && urldecode($_GET['fname'])=="slct") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Please select a forum you saw me on</option>
   <option value="hf" <?php if($_GET['fname'] && urldecode($_GET['fname'])=="hf") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Hackforums (_Jony_)</option>
   <option value="sy" <?php if($_GET['fname'] && urldecode($_GET['fname'])=="sy") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Sythe (Purepks0r)</option>
   <option value="rs" <?php if($_GET['fname'] && urldecode($_GET['fname'])=="rs") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>R-S (Purepks0r)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried changing it but it doesn't really fixes my issue. thanks for the reply though.

Comment: If i remove fname, it will still show the error because the system is checking if $fname is empty

Comment: Not working, I just added the old fname field and it worked, but it ignored the select field data, it didn't send it to the panel.. It's has nothign to do with the HTML i think. probably in config.ini